# What is the right way to pass array of objects with redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js and I need to pass an array of objects with `res.redirect()`,
I tried with querystring but it's not a good idea because the array with too big and I could get `Error 414 Request URI too long`.
using `connect-flash` isn't a good way either, it's more useful for passing messages.
And I don't want to use `req.app.locals` for that.

Hope you can help me with any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the client here is a browser that you want to just automatically follow the redirect and then inherit some new state when the server generates the page for that newly redirected URL, then here are some options:

1. If you already have a session established for the user, then you can store the data in the session, then include a single query parameter that tells the route handler for the page you're redirecting to to look in the session to get the relevant data.
2. You could also create a temporary server-side cache of data.  Generate a random key (likely a timestamp plus a random number).  Store the data in a server-side `Map` using that key.  Then put the key into a query string on the redirect.  Then, in the route handler for the new, redirected page, it will see the query string parameter and it can grab that key out of the query string and access the data from the server-side `Map` serving as a temporary cache (and probably remove it from the cache too).  This scheme works in a session-less environment.

   You then need some scheme for cleaning up unused data from the cache so it doesn't accumulate.  Probably what makes sense it to timestamp the data and then have a `setInterval()` timer that just removes things from the `Map` if their timestamp is older than xx minutes.

If the request is an Ajax call rather than a regular browser page request, then you don't need to use a redirect at all.  You can just return the content that they would have gotten if they then followed your redirect.  Then, you don't have to invent a temporary place to store the data.  You can just use the data to generate the desired page and return it.

Comment: Yeah, I used exactly the way you suggested (option 2) before you posted your answer. (-;

Answer (score 0):

Store the data as session data and serve it back up to them when they land on the landing page.

Another way would be to have the client request the data asynchronously once the redirect has been performed.